# Temporarily disable Meteor testing packages (e.g. Velocity + Mocha) without removing them

Tags: meteor, mocha.js, velocity

Mostly all of the testing lines printed to the console get in my way, especially when I'm just setting up a new project or trying to get this one code bit down that the testing framework isn't too helpful for. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I was able to disable Velocity via

```
VELOCITY=0
```

Before running the server, so basically I ran

```
VELOCITY=0 meteor run
```

Comment: That does work now but [used to not work with certain test runners](https://github.com/meteor-velocity/velocity/issues/270#issuecomment-84518481).

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that creating a new Meteor project doesn't install Velocity or Mocha by default, so if you have them it's probably because they were manually installed or part of a boilerplate project that you're using.

Having said that, I think it's safe to remove these packages. More than likely, if you have Velocity and Mocha installed, you need to run the following:

```
meteor remove mike:mocha velocity:core
```

There might be other testing-related packages that need to remove. To find out what other packages are installed for your project, you can run the following:

```
meteor list
```

Then just remove individual packages as needed.

Comment: I actually made a mini-boilerplate for myself and added them since I figured I should get more into TDD. I was just hoping for some solution or flag I could use to run the server without it for a bit short bit -- even though it's unlikely, suppose I was stranded without internet when I really needed that testing framework and I had just removed it. hahah idk, it's just a small convenience thing

Comment: In that case you might have some luck by issuing the flags shown in this issue: https://github.com/meteor-velocity/velocity/issues/210.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the `VELOCITY=0` environment variable, I've found that pressing <kbd>Ctrl+V</kbd> in the client window will temporarily disable Velocity on that client, which will stop the tests from printing things in the console. Pressing it again will re-enable it.